# Formatting a external HDD and the computer turn off

Tags: external-hdd, format, fsck

I was running the command "sudo fsck -cfvr / dev / sdc1" on an external hard drive, when I return to the computer, it was off. I do not know if the task was finished or not.

How can I know if before the computer was turned off the task would have finished or not?

Comment: I don't think that the command worked as you expected. The command you used tried to check the root file system and should have aborted because the root file system is mounted. You should have used `sudo fsck -cfvr /dev/sdc1` instead of `sudo fsck -cfvr / dev / sdc1`.

Comment: Yes, the command was working correctly, the file system was not mounted at the time of running the command. I already had a percentage greater than 50% the last time I checked it. but then it suddenly went out and I do not know if 100% of the process would end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the computer shut off because the battery ran out... and if you were trying to badblock the /dev/sdc1 partition... then it didn't complete. **Never** run `fsck` whilst on battery alone.

And... if you were trying to badblock /dev/sdc1, you didn't give it a proper command. It should be...

`sudo e2fsck -fck /dev/sdc1` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fcck /dev/sdc1` # non-destructive read/write test

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fcck parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.
```